# AspNet Core MVC + Class Library (.Net Standard) with Entity Framework

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, visual-studio-2017, entity-framework-core

I'm using Visual Studio 2017 and I'm building my first Asp.Net Core MVC site and I want to create also a Class Library (.Net Standard) as My Data Access Layer. In this last library I want to use Entity Framework to connect to my database.
I tried to use Entity Framework Core but I don't know how to create an EDMX file to map my database.
Is there another way to do this with Entity Framework Core?

Thanks in advance for your help :)

Comment: Also, If your web app is going to be single paged then I strongly recommend checking out AngularJS too, the models for development are quite different, but it is super powerful. Google is your best friend with MVC, but its about knowing where to look.

Answer (score 0):

Entity framework has the power to the point that you may consider not explicitly mapping any of your database at first. Entity framework does most of the mapping for you.

I was in the same boat as you about a year ago and I got a lot of help from this example. It is the Contoso University Example: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/creating-an-entity-framework-data-model-for-an-asp-net-mvc-application

Comment: Thank you Travis, I already used Contoso University example to learn building web apps with MVC 5 and Entity Framework...is a very nice example.
Actually my problem is that I want to build an MVC "Core" Cross platform Web Application leaving Entity Framework in a separated project (Data Access Layer).
Did you already try this solution ?

Comment: Ahh, so you want to separate the entire DAL into a whole other project? This is the best I could find on advising separation of stuff into different projects. Perzsonally i would say "NOOOO DONT DO IT!!!" Because of some nightmares I am currently working through as a result of doing that lol but read this and tell me what you think. https://forums.asp.net/post/5832808.aspx

Comment: Yes, I usually structure the solution as follow:

- DAL: the acces to DB (Entity Framework) library
- BL: the Business Layer containing business logic classes
- MVC: the MVC web site (Presentation Layer)
- Common: the classes common to all application and Utilities classes
- Models: a model library containing model classes used to pass data from BL and MVC projects. Helps me to implement a best separation between modules.

Actually my problem is with Asp.Net MVC "Core" 1.1, you know? I can't use Entity Framework in a separated .Net Class Library (Standard)